# Set up customized Jwt Grant Handler when using Helm installation of WSO2 Api Manager 3.x

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have developed a custom JWTBearerGrantHandler which is packaged as a jar. In a bare metal WSO2 deployment I would add that jar into `repository/components/lib` and setup the relevant class in `repository/resources/conf/default.json`:

```
  "oauth.grant_type.jwt_bearer.grant_handler": "xxx.MyJWTBearerGrantHandler",
```

However I want to deploy WSO2 API Manager in Kubernetes using the provided Helm chart (https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/advanced/am-pattern-1). In this case, how can I add my custom handler?

Answer (score 0):

Both changes, adding JAR and configuration(`repository/resources/conf/default.json`) can be done by building a Docker image. In this case, the base image would be the WSO2 provided Docker image for WSO2 API Manager and you can use Docker `COPY` Dockerfile instruction to add JAR + configuration file into the Docker image. Once the image is built and pushed to a private registry, please refer to the image via [values.yaml](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/eb0daea90b69c06ac9a8dd228b906a4dda63c290/advanced/am-pattern-1/values.yaml#L58-L63).

Another way of adding the JAR file, assuming the JAR file is remotely accessible, is downloading the JAR using an Init container. Please have a look at how the MySQL connector is getting downloaded [using init container](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/eb0daea90b69c06ac9a8dd228b906a4dda63c290/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-2/wso2am-pattern-1-am-deployment.yaml#L41).

If the given configuration is changing often, it is best to apply it via a
K8s Configmap. To add `repository/resources/conf/default.json` as a Configmap, please have a look at an existing [configuration mount](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-2/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml)